# Install Java web app with embedded Tomcat on windows (using system tray to manage)

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, windows-installer

I was given a task to make an installer for our application on Windows. It should be some *.exe or *.msi file. That application is made with grails and is packaged to a war file with embedded Tomcat, which can be started as "java -Dgrails.env=production -jar x.war" We need a shortcut to start that application, then in system tray should appear an icon, which will allow to stop the application (the server). The app needs to be installed at the specified path and a few parameters should be saved in some config file. I googled some information about installers, it seems easy to understand what to do if you have simple jar desktop app, but in our case it is an embedded server which needs to be manged via system tray, so I do not really know which tool I can use to implement this. Unfortunately, we cannot afford commercial solution. What suggestions you may have?

Comment: take look at Tomcat windows service wrapper, is open source and probably is based on general java service starter , which has wider usage. Many years ago I had a look. BTW: service systray contrloer!=instaler

Answer (score 0):

Long long time ago I used this:[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Also you will probably need tomcat wrapper.

[Take a look at following example:](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php?title=A_script_to_install_a_Tomcat_web_application&oldid=15111)